Hibernate pesimistick locking not working with sprinboot transactions
I'm using hibernate with springboot, but I can't figure out, why I don't see locking statements in logs, I see all statements, selects, updates, but no locks.
MySQL 8.3 Tables are innodb stored
configuration:
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
logging.level.org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener=DEBUG
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=error
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false

repository:
interface JournalLogRepository : Repository<JournalLog, UUID> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    fun save(journalLog: JournalLog)

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    fun getById(id: UUID): JournalLog

...

example output:
 o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]

org.hibernate.SQL                        : select jl1_0.id,jl1_0.date_create...

o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]

o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 1 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects

o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [...SpringTransactionTest.doInTransaction]
o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getById]
selects...
o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getById]
TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
then update sql



Just resolved it, you cannot use @Lock on auto-generated spring repository methods, you have to write then as a query.
interface JournalLogRepository : Repository<JournalLog, UUID> {
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query("select j from JournalLog j where j.id = :id") //will work, adds `for update` to select

@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
fun getForUpdate(id: UUID): JournalLog //will not work

...
